.NET Standard not working on .NET Framework 4.7.2
I have a .NET Framework 4.7.2 project (console app) for which I've done a NuGet DLL update to a version which they say it depends on .NET 4.8 or .Net Standard. I expected this to work since .Net Standard is compatible with .NET Framework 4.7.2.
Now I'm facing this error:

CS0012 The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.  CreateCommandRouterProxy

for this I've added a reference to netstandard as per this question which it resolved with this path:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.7.2\Facades\netstandard.dll
I have checked the DLL version from there using sn and it has the expected PublicKeyToken. Any help is much appreciated!

There are multiple versions of .NET Standard: which are you targeting? (Or, include your project file in the question.)

@Richard the netstandard dll has verson 4.7.3062.0. I assume this is 2.0 since it automatically got resolved this way, but I don't know a way to check the DLL itself

Given this is a NuGet package: check the https://nuget.org/ page for the package: the Frameworks tab highlights that is directly targeted (rather than just compatible). Eg. xunit.assert (for want of a better example) targets netstandard1.1 and .net6.0. Having specifics (ie. what are you dependencies?) would make this easier.

"I expected this to work since .Net Standard is compatible with .NET Framework 4.7.2." Not necessarily. .NET Standard 2.1 is not compatible with any version of .NET Framework at all. Which Nuget package are you using and what version?

@phuzi I have decompiled the netstandard library and it is v2.0 so it should be compatible. the only thing that gets my attention is that it is marked as reference assembly and I'm not sure if this has any impact.

what happens if you add a reference as per the answer and not the question, i.e. actual assembly and not the reference assembly? afaik for 4.7.2 they have a "real" netstandard.dll in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

@IvanPetrov thanks for the suggestion! It does produce the same error.

What are you trying to upgrade? The console app or a library? .Net Standard is a contract, not a runtime. The primary project still needs to run .Net 4.7.2, .Net Core, or .Net 5+.

Try adding this to your .csproj file: <PropertyGroup>   <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>   <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType> </PropertyGroup>

@ElDuderino I am trying to upgrade a nuget - Serialize.Linq to latest version from an older one which was compatible with .NET Framework 4.6. The latest version supports only .NET Framework 4.8 or .Net Standard. The primary project is still 4.7.2, I haven't changed that.

If it needs 4.8 and you're on 4.7.2, then you won't be able to use it :) The latest version doesn't say .Net Standard. But even if it did, .Net Standard is just a contract. .Net Standard just ensures the dll is compatible with different runtimes. Your runtime, the executable running the program, is still 4.7.2.

@ElDuderino not really, because it also supports .net standard 2.0. I've created a sandbox console app 4.7.2 and successfully ran with that version of Serialize.Linq which does not compile on the main console app. So I'm clueless to why that happens...
